# Copy file and name it a value from the active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need this code to copy the Word file and call it a value from the active cell

```
FileCopy Application.ThisWorkbook.path & "\template.docx", Application.ThisWorkbook.path & "\exercies\ & Worksheets(1).ActiveCell.Value & "".docx"
```

But it gives me an error "Bad file of number".
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this part of your code:

```
"\exercies\ & Worksheets(1).ActiveCell.Value & "".docx"
```

If you `Debug.Print` this part of the statement, you'll get:

```
\exercies\ & Worksheets(1).ActiveCell.Value & ".docx
```

which is not a valid path.

Try replacing it with this instead:

```
"\exercies\" & ActiveCell.Value & ".docx"
```

which will produce a valid path. Furthermore, I suspect you have misspelled the folder name. Shouldn't it be **exercises** instead?